# How do you get data from two relational tables without a 1:1 relationship? - MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization, inner-join

I have two relational tables, `core` and `domains`. They are both related by `core.id` and `domains.cid`. I want to form one query that can return one row in the `core` table, with all related rows from the `domains` table. At the moment, I run two queries; one to get the single row needed from the `core` table, and another to get all related rows from the `domains` table but I'm trying to optimise my queries.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT a.domain,b.* FROM domains a WHERE a.cid=1 INNER JOIN core b ON a.cid=b.id
```

Now this works fine, except it returns multiple rows all with redundant data. For example, if one row in `core` has 5 related rows in `domains`, then 5 rows are returned, and `b.*` is obviously the same in each result. Is there a way to return one row, with all `a.domain` returned in the single row?

Comment: You will have to create a SQLFIDDLE example because what you need (PIVOT-ing table data) is not very intuitive and easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(d.domain) AS domains,
  c.*
FROM core c
JOIN domains d
  ON d.cid = c.id
WHERE c.id = 1
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: Could you add a bit of commentary on the use of `GROUP_CONCAT` please?

Comment: @JeremySmyth It concatenates all values from the specified field into one string (per group). Here's documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Can you explain the use of `JOIN` with the `GROUP_CONCAT`? Why not `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @KeirSimmons `JOIN` *is* `INNER JOIN`. It's just a shorter way to write it.